# Python - how to add property accessors programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, accessor

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      for item in ["itemA", "itemB"]:
          setattr(self, item, property(lambda : self.__get_method(item)))

   def __get_method(self, item):
       # do some stuff and return result
       # this is pretty complex method which requires db lookups etc. 
       return result
```

I am trying to come up with above example to create class properties during init. Items list will get bigger in the future and don't want to add `@property` every time new entry is added.

However can't get the result from property but object location.

```py
a = A()
a.itemA # returns <property at 0x113a41590>
```

Initially it was like this and realized this could be better.

```py
class A:
    @property
    def itemA(self):
        return self.__get_method("itemA") 
    
    @property
    def itemX(self):
        ...
    # and so on
```

How could I add new properties just by adding new entries to the `items` list and the class itself will create accessor for it?

Comment: Properties must belong to the *class* to work. So if you really want to do this, just after your class definition, do something like `ffor item in ["itemA", "itemB"]: setattr(A, item, property((lambda item: lambda self: self._A__get_method(item))(item)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to @juanpa.arrivillaga comment.
You also can implement `__getattr__` method

For example:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        #make everybody happy
```